# Riemann sum formula for definite integral using prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

I had asked this question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2921560/is-this-riemann-integral-for-prime-numbers-true). It got lot of upvotes but no answer (except one which was too long to be posted as a comment) hence I am posting it in MO.

While answering another [question in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917887/do-arithmetic-mean-and-geometric-mean-of-prime-numbers-converge/2919825#2919825) I had used the following result which I thought was a trivial consequence of the prime number theorem and equidistribution.  However, I realized from the comments that many people  thought that this was not either true or counter intuitive. Hence I am posting this as a question looking for a proof or disproof.

> Let $p_k$ be the $k$-th prime and $f$ be a continuous function
>   Riemann integrable in $(0,1)$ such that
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r = 1}^{n}f\Big(\frac{r}{n}\Big)
> = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx.  $$
>
> Then,    $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r =
> 1}^{n}f\Big(\frac{p_r}{p_n}\Big) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx. $$

**My approach**: It was was based on showing that as $n \to \infty$, the ratios $p_r/p_n$ approached equidistribution in $(0,1)$ hence the integral follows as a  property of equidistributed sequence.

**Motivation**: There are several identities, limits etc on prime numbers which can be easily proven using this simple formula.

Comment: One avenue of proof (probably similar to the one you describe) is to use the prime number theorem with error term to say that every interval of length $p_n/\log p_n$ between $0$ and $p_n$ has approximately $1/\log p_n$ of the primes being summed, then approximate each $f(p_r/p_n)$ by the nearby value $f(kn/\log p_n)$ for the appropriate $k$, then sum.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The statement follows from the prime number theorem. By an approximation argument, we can assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$. Then,
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{p_r}{p_n}\right)=\int_0^1 f(x)\,d\pi(p_n x)=nf(1)-\int_0^1 f'(x)\pi(p_n x)\,dx.$$
We estimate the last integral for fixed $f$:
$$\int_0^1 f'(x)\pi(p_n x)\,dx=\int_{\frac{1}{\log n}}^1 f'(x)\pi(p_n x)\,dx+o(n).$$
In the last integral, we have by the prime number theorem,
$$\pi(p_n x)\sim\frac{p_n x}{\log(p_n x)}\sim\frac{p_n x}{\log n}\sim nx,$$
so that
\begin{align*}\int_0^1 f'(x)\pi(p_n x)\,dx
&=\int_{\frac{1}{\log n}}^1 f'(x)\bigl(nx+o(nx)\bigr)\,dx+o(n)\\
&=\int_{0}^1 f'(x)\bigl(nx+o(nx)\bigr)\,dx+o(n)\\
&=n\int_0^1 f'(x)x\,dx+o(n)\\
&=nf(1)-n\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx + o(n).
\end{align*}
Putting everything together,
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{p_r}{p_n}\right)=n\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx + o(n),$$
that is,
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{p_r}{p_n}\right)=\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx + o(1).$$